Why Isn't a Bris done to the exact hour?
The Torah says a bris is performed on the 8th day of the child's life. Why doesn't this mean to the exact hour? Meaning, if the child was born at 1pm, only on the 8th day at 1pm should the bris be performed. Only then is the child a full 8 days. Why in fact is this not the case?

Because it doesn't say "on the 169th hour"

The 8th day at the same time would be 7 full days btw

ok @shmosel, so the following day. Why don't we wait 8 days "mies lies"? Also With regards to kodshim wo do find this concept of counting to the hour (look at zevachim 25b in regards to a korban pesach).

https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.5a.11

Note we do wait 168 hours if the child was born sick even if he recovers that day (common enough, eg newborn tachypnea)

Should shavuos begin on the same hour of the day that the omer was brought?
